# How to add my Telegram bot to existing private channel

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is there a way to add my Telegram bot to existing private channel?
When I click 'Add to group' button on my bot's profile page, I cannot see this channel in list, though I am in this channel.

Comment: it is not possible to add a bot to channels as a member!(only they can be admins of channels)...are you the channel's admin or creator?

Comment: @tashakori I'm not. I'm thinking of the way to get updates fro channel and immediately take actions programmatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bots can only be admin of a channel. You should be the creator or authorized admin of that channel to be able to add a bot as an admin of that channel.

Ask the authorized admin to add your bot to that channel, otherwise use telegram clients instead of bots. (Telegram is open source and has released cli, web, android,... source codes)